# How to push lower row items of a flex box further down to create space for addtional content upon click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I created an HTML flex-box that displays images based on data returned from API which is somewhat like this:-
[![THIS][1]][1]

Now I want to display additional data upon clicking on a specific div element.So that the lower divs move further down and create space for "expand" section 
[![Say like space for tiffin is produced in here][2]][2]

Answer (score 0):

Why not insert a placeholder flex row below each specific flex data row?

I created an demo where you can run this snippet and click each row to figure out if it works for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <style>
        ul,
        li {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .flex-box {
            width: 800px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .flex-box__nav {
            display: flex;
        }

        .flex-box__item {
            flex: 1;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .flex-box__collapse {
            display: none;
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="flex-box">
        <ul class="flex-box__nav">
            <li class="flex-box__item">click me
                <img src="">
            </li>
            <li class="flex-box__item">click me
                <img src="">
            </li>
            <li class="flex-box__item">click me
                <img src="">
            </li>
            <li class="flex-box__item">click me
                <img src="">
            </li>
            <li class="flex-box__item">click me
                <img src="">
            </li>
            <li class="flex-box__item">click me
                <img src="">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="flex-box__collapse">
            collapsed area
        </div>
        <ul class="flex-box__nav">
            <li class="flex-box__item">click me
                <img src="">
            </li>
            <li class="flex-box__item">click me
                <img src="">
            </li>
            <li class="flex-box__item">click me
                <img src="">
            </li>
            <li class="flex-box__item">click me
                <img src="">
            </li>
            <li class="flex-box__item">click me
                <img src="">
            </li>
            <li class="flex-box__item">click me
                <img src="">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="flex-box__collapse">
            collapsed area
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function clickHanlder() {
            var isCollapse = true;
            return function () {
                this.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.display = isCollapse ? "block" : "none";
                isCollapse = !isCollapse;
            }
        }

        document.querySelectorAll(".flex-box__nav").forEach(function (val) {
            val.onclick = clickHanlder();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```